# tmux random characters appearing in terminal

Tags: bash, command-line, tmux

I'm experiencing a strange problem with tmux appearing whenever I enter copy mode and I have multiple panes.
Basically, after I select the text, when I press Enter (vi-mode) or Alt-w (emacs-mode) a lot of strange characters appear on the terminal.

Here you can see two example demos of what I'm saying

[Gif 1](http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=201702262112E8JCTIPT9IeQJ7gf4M3N&file=output_3sIZiQ.gif)
[Gif 2](http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=20170226210nVeqHwcgetckVsZUaGQv4&file=output_qY7uRh.gif)

If it can be useful, I'm using the bash shell with the solarized-dark theme.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, the images have disappeared by now, so this question decays to "we can't really tell what's going on". I hope you found a solution (you can answer your own questions) or upload the pictures again and I'll inline them.